# Center text in screen vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not sure how to center my text vertically. Basically, when I click a button the page will gray out with a loading text. I managed to center it horizontally but can't do it in vertical.

[image: Example Image]

CSS

```
.LockOff {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.LockOn {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20%;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    opacity: 0.75;
}
.lockMsg {
    color:black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function lockScreen() {
        var lock = document.getElementById('divLock');

        if (lock)
            lock.className = 'LockOn';

        lock.innerHTML = "<h1 class=\"lockMsg\">YOUR REQUEST IS BEING PROCESSED. PLEASE WAIT.</h1>";
    }
</script>

<div id="divLock" class="LockOff"></div>
```

Comment: @OregonTrail it's `top:50%` and `transform: translateY(-50%)`, the -50% for translateY is 50% of the element's height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your CSS a little bit to achieve that as:

```
.LockOn {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    opacity: 0.75;
}
.lockMsg {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add these three lines to your css for `.LockOn`

```
.LockOn{
   display:flex;
   align-items:center;
   justify-content:center;
}
```

Here's a working snippet. I changed your script a liitle bit to show it working.

```js
(function lockScreen() {
        var lock = document.getElementById('divLock');

        if (lock){
            lock.className = 'LockOn';
          }

        lock.innerHTML = "<h1 class='lockMsg'>YOUR REQUEST IS BEING PROCESSED. PLEASE WAIT.</h1>";
})();
```

```css
.LockOff {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.LockOn {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    bottom: 0px;
    top:0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    opacity: 0.75;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}
.lockMsg {
    color:black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="divLock" class="LockOff"></div>
```

Comment: Hi kittCat, thank you for the detailed answer. Unfortunately, VS is prompting the error that flex is not a valid value for the display property and both align-items and justify-content is not a known CSS property